# Python shared references

Tags: python

I am confused with the following code

```
L1 = [3,6,9,12]
L2 = [L1]*3
L3=[list(L1)]*3
L4 = [list(L1) for i in range(3)]
L1[0]=100

 L2
[[100, 6, 9, 12], [100, 6, 9, 12], [100, 6, 9, 12]]

L3
[[3, 6, 9, 12], [3, 6, 9, 12], [3, 6, 9, 12]]

L4
[[3, 6, 9, 12], [3, 6, 9, 12], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

Why `L3` and `L4` not affected by the fifth line of code? It means that only `L2` has shared object with `L1`. Can someone explain why `L3` and `L4` do not create shared object and only `L2` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list(foo)` creates a new list object that copies the individual values of the items in `foo`. Thus modifying the `foo` object (in your case, `L1`) will not affect which values are in the new list.

`L2` is a list which contains 3 references to `L1`.

`L3` and `L4` are lists which contain 3 copies of `L1` each.

You can use the `id()` function to observe this.

Comment: Specifically it shallow-copies the list; changing an entire element won't reflect the changes, but mutating any object within will.